# Web client AngularJS Multi-panel page blank though there is contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to use a nice multi-panel example given [here](http://layout.jquery-dev.com/demos/accordions_and_tabs_inside_layout.html) in a page being included using Angular's `ng-include` directive.

The contents of the page is:

```
<div id="ThisisthemainPage" ng-controller="Main_Working_Page_Controller" style="height:100%">

    <style type="text/css">
        /* neutralize pane formatting BEFORE loading UI Theme */
        .ui-layout-pane ,
        .ui-layout-content {
            background: none;
            border:     0;
            padding:    0;
            overflow:   hide;                                  /* FD was: overflow: visible; */
        }

        p               { margin:       1em 0; }

        /* use !important to override UI theme styles */
        .grey           { background:   #758 !important; }     /* FD was: #999 */
        .outline        { /*border:     1px dashed #F00 !important;*/ }
        .add-padding    { padding:      3px !important; }      /* FD was: 10px */
        .no-padding     { padding:      0 !important; }
        .add-scrollbar  { overflow:     auto; }
        .no-scrollbar   { overflow:     hidden; }
        .allow-overflow { overflow:     visible; }
        .full-height    { height:       100%; }
        button          { cursor:       pointer; }

    </style>


<div class="ui-layout-north ui-widget-content add-padding" style="text-align:center;vertical_align:middle">
    <h3>Stationary - Contains Global Steering parameters ("From"/"To", District selection, etc.)</h3>
</div> 
<div class="ui-layout-south ui-widget-content add-padding">
    South
</div> 


<div class="ui-layout-west no-scrollbar add-padding grey">
    <div id="accordion-west">

        <H4 style="background:black"><b><a href="#">Management</a></b></H4>
        <div>
<!--                <ul class="treeView" style="padding-left: 10px;">-->
            <ul style="padding-left: 10px;">

                <li>Add Location</li>
                <li>Alter Location</li>
                <li>Add Tests Bundle</li>
                <li>Alter Tests Bundle</li>
                <li>Do other 5</li>
                <li>Do other 6</li>
                <li>Do other 7</li>
                <li>Do other 8</li>
                <li>Do other 9</li>
                <li>Do other 10</li>
                <li>Do other 11</li>
                <li>Do other 12</li>
                <li>Do other 13</li>
                <li>Do other 14</li>
                <li>Do other 15</li>
                <li>Do other 16</li>
                <li>Do other 17</li>
                <li>Do other 18</li>
                <li>Do other 19</li>
                <li>Do other 20</li>
                <li>Do other 21</li>
                <li>Do other 22</li>
                <li>Do other 23</li>
                <li>Do other 24</li>
                <li>Do other 25</li>
                <li>...</li>

            </ul>
        </div>

        <H4><b><a href="#">Queries</a></b></H4>
        <div>
            <ul class="collapsibleList" style="padding-left: 10px;">
                <li>Samplings</li>
                <ul class="collapsibleList">
                    <li>Get List of Planned Samplings</li>
                    <li>Get List of Executed Samplings</li>
                </ul>
                <li>Get List of Places (with filters)</li>
                <li>Get List of Standards Overflow</li>
                <li>...</li>

            </ul>
        </div>

        <H4><b><a href="#">Data Entry</a></b></H4>
        <div>
            <ul class="collapsibleList" style="padding-left: 10px;">
                <li>Enter Tests Results</li>
                <li>Create new Sample</li>
                <li>...</li>

            </ul>
        </div>

        <H4><b><a href="#">Actions</a></b></H4>
        <div>
            <ul class="collapsibleList" style="padding-left: 10px;">
                <li>Review Test Results</li>
                <li>Create new Sampling Request</li>
                <li>Cancel Sampling Request</li>
                <li>...</li>

            </ul>
        </div>

        <H4><b><a href="#">Forms</a></b></H4>
        <div>
            <ul class="collapsibleList" style="padding-left: 10px;">
                <li>Create sampling Form</li>
                <li>...</li>

            </ul>
        </div>    

        <H4><b><a href="#">Reports</a></b></H4>
        <div>
            <ul class="collapsibleList" style="padding-left: 10px;">
                <li>Internal</li>
                <ul>
                    <li>Plan vs. Performance</li>
                    <li>...</li>

                </ul>
                <li>Health Ministry</li>
                <li>...</li>

            </ul>
        </div>    

        <H4><b><a href="#">Repository</a></b></H4>
        <div>
            Provides access to historical information (e.g. reports).
        </div>    

       </div>
    </div>


    <div id="tabs-center" class="ui-layout-center no-scrollbar add-padding grey">
        <!-- center Tabs layout -->
        <UL class="ui-layout-north no-scrollbar allow-overflow">
            <LI><a href="#tab-panel-center-1">(1) View Sampling Requests List</a></LI>
            <LI><a href="#tab-panel-center-2">(2) Generate Report: Monthly Sampling Log</a></LI>
            <LI><a href="#tab-panel-center-3">(3) Test Results Entry</a></LI>
       </UL>
       <div class="ui-layout-center ui-widget-content add-scrollbar" style="border-top: 0;">
           <div id="tab-panel-center-1" class="outline">
               <B>Example of menu at the left:</B>

               <ul class="treeView">
                   <li>
                    Reports
                    <ul class="collapsibleList">
                    <li class="collapsibleListClosed" style="-ms-user-select: none;">
                        Sampling
                        <ul class="collapsibleList" style="display: none;">
                            <li class="collapsibleListClosed" style="-ms-user-select: none;">
                                Planned
                                <ul class="collapsibleList" style="display: none;">
                                    <li style="-ms-user-select: none;">Automatically</li>
                                    <li style="-ms-user-select: none;">Manually</li>
                                    <li class="lastChild" style="-ms-user-select: none;">And cancelled</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="lastChild collapsibleListClosed" style="-ms-user-select: none;">
                                Executed
                                <ul class="collapsibleList" style="display: none;">
                                    <li style="-ms-user-select: none;">Expanding/opening</li>
                                    <li class="lastChild" style="-ms-user-select: none;">Collapsing/closing</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="lastChild collapsibleListClosed" style="-ms-user-select: none;">
                            Overflows
                            <ul class="collapsibleList" style="display: none;">
                                <li class="collapsibleListClosed" style="-ms-user-select: none;">
                                    Quimistry
                                    <ul class="collapsibleList" style="display: none;">
                                        <li style="-ms-user-select: none;">Automatically</li>
                                        <li style="-ms-user-select: none;">Manually</li>
                                        <li class="lastChild" style="-ms-user-select: none;">And cancelled</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="lastChild collapsibleListClosed" style="-ms-user-select: none;">
                                    Biology
                                    <ul class="collapsibleList" style="display: none;">
                                        <li style="-ms-user-select: none;">Expanding/opening</li>
                                        <li class="lastChild" style="-ms-user-select: none;">Collapsing/closing</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                       </ul>
                   </li>
               </ul>                




           </div>
           <div id="tab-panel-center-2" class="no-padding no-scrollbar"
                style="position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;">
               <!-- center Accordion layout -->
               <div class="ui-layout-center no-scrollbar add-padding">
                    <div class="ui-widget-header add-padding" >
                       ACCORDION HEADER
                   </div>
                   <!-- <div class="ui-layout-content no-scrollbar"> -->
                   <div class="ui-layout-content scrollbar">
                       <div id="accordion-center">

                           <H3><a href="#">Management</a></H3>
                           <div>
                               <B>Accordion inside a layout-pane</B>
                               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
                                   Vestibulum condimentum neque a velit laoreet dapibus. 
                                   Etiam eleifend tempus pharetra.</p>
                               <p>.</p><p>.</p><p>.</p><p>.</p><p>.</p><p>.</p><p>.</p><p>.</p><p>.</p><p>.</p>
                               <p>.</p><p>.</p><p>.</p><p>.</p><p>.</p><p>.</p><p>.</p><p>.</p><p>.</p><p>.</p>
                               <p>.</p><p>.</p><p>.</p><p>.</p><p>.</p><p>.</p><p>.</p><p>.</p><p>.</p><p>.</p>
                           </div>

                           <H3><a href="#">Data Queries</a></H3>
                           <div>
                               <p style="font-weight: bold;">Sed Non Urna</p>
                               <p>Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus.
                                    Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor velit,
                                   faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo.</p>
                               <p>Vivamus non quam. In suscipit faucibus urna.</p>
                           </div>

                           <H3><a href="#">Data Entry</a></H3>
                           <div>
                               Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis.
                               Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede.
                           </div>

                           <H3><a href="#">Reports</a></H3>
                           <div>
                               <p>Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames 
                                   ac turpis egestas.</p>
                               <p>Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;
                                   Aenean lacinia mauris vel est.</p>
                               <p>Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus.
                                   Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
                           </div>


                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
               <!-- /center Accordion layout -->
           </div>
           <div id="tab-panel-center-3" class="outline">
               Cras nec arcu sed nisi varius fermentum ut non nulla. Pellentesque ultricies condimentum nibh, 
               nec imperdiet felis laoreet sit amet.
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-layout-south ui-state-disabled ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom no-scrollbar add-padding">
          Status indication, notifications, etc.
        </div>
    <!-- /center Tabs layout -->
    </div>

</div>
```

and the controller:

```
MyApp.controller('Main_Working_Page_Controller' , ['$rootScope' , '$scope' ,  'DB_Services' , function( $rootScope , $scope , DB_Services) {


    $scope.Initializa_Page = function () {

        // alias callback for convenience
        resizePaneAccordions    = $.layout.callbacks.resizePaneAccordions;
        resizeTabLayout         = $.layout.callbacks.resizeTabLayout;

        // OUTER/PAGE LAYOUT
//      pageLayout = $("body").layout({ // DO NOT use "var pageLayout" here
        pageLayout = $("#ThisisthemainPage").layout({ // DO NOT use "var pageLayout" here
            west__size:         .15 
        ,   east__size:         .0 
        ,   north__size:        .1 
        ,   south__initClosed:  true
        ,   north__initClosed:  false  /* FD was true */
        ,   west__onresize:     resizePaneAccordions // west accordion a child of pane
        ,   east__onresize:     resizePaneAccordions // east accordion nested inside a tab-panel
        }); 

        // TABS IN CENTER-PANE
        // create tabs before wrapper-layout so elems are correct size before creating layout
        pageLayout.panes.center.tabs({
            activate:           resizeTabLayout // tab2-accordion is wrapped in a layout
        });

        // WRAPPER-LAYOUT FOR TABS/TAB-PANELS, INSIDE OUTER-CENTER PANE
        pageLayout.panes.center.layout({
            closable:           false
        ,   resizable:          false
        ,   spacing_open:       0
        ,   center__onresize:   resizeTabLayout // tabs/panels are wrapped with an inner-layout
        });

        // LAYOUT TO CONTAIN HEADER+ACCORDION, INSIDE A TAB, INSIDE OUTER-CENTER PANE
        $("#tab-panel-center-2").layout({
            center__onresize:   resizePaneAccordions // accordion is inside center-pane
        ,   resizeWithWindow:   false   // resizing is handled by callbacks to ensure the correct resizing sequence
        ,   triggerEventsOnLoad: true   // force resize of accordion when layout inits - ie, becomes visible 1st time
        });

//       TABS INSIDE EAST-PANE
//      pageLayout.panes.east.tabs({
//          activate:           resizePaneAccordions // resize tab2-accordion when tab is activated
//      });
//      pageLayout.sizeContent("east"); // resize pane-content-elements after creating east-tabs

        // INIT ALL ACCORDIONS - EVEN THOSE NOT VISIBLE
        $("#accordion-west")    .accordion({ heightStyle: "fill" });
        $("#accordion-center")  .accordion({ heightStyle: "fill" });


        // THEME SWITCHER
        addThemeSwitcher('#east-toolbar',{ top: '12px', right: '5px' });
        // if a new theme is applied, it could change the height of some content,
        // so call resizeAll to 'correct' any header/footer heights affected
        // NOTE: this is only necessary because we are changing CSS *AFTER LOADING* using themeSwitcher
        setTimeout( pageLayout.resizeAll, 2000 ); /* allow time for browser to re-render with new theme */
    } ;

    console.log("Calling Initializa_Page") ;
    $scope.Initializa_Page() ;

}]) ;
```

The strange thing is that, while the page appears completely blank, when using the debugging tools of CHROME and checking the HTML, the various elements (I would say all of them) and marked as present (light blue rectangles whenever you place the mouse on top of the HTML definition of the element).

So, elements **ARE** there but are not visible at all. I'm obviously missing something but don't know what.

### Edit

I have added a screenshot.

I'm adding a sample screenshot that demonstrates the issue, meaning the **ROOM** for all elements is allocated, but the elements are not being shown.

[image: Elements not shown though their location and size are correct.]

Comment: Can you let me know where are you using $scope.Initializa_Page in the html page?

Comment: It is invoked as the last command within the relevant controller (see second piece of source above).

Comment: Just wanted to know where it is invoked in the first piece of source above.